# Ejabberd mod_push

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp, ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd and wanted to accomplish a functionality of push notifications.
According to documentation it says ejabberd only handles the server part.

I will use FCM to deliver push notifications to android and I am already using a nodejs app server which is connected to mysql.

**Expectation: I want to push that offline message to the nodejs app server where I can manage get token info which I will save into mysql and will trigger FCM from there.
Just like in following url :** [url_to_nodejs_signaling_server](https://shockoe.com/ideas/development/creating-a-push-notification-server-with-node-js/)

I went through many articles but there are outdated ones.Some says to create offline_hooks but I dont find any good article for it. I want to use my nodejs server to handles the trigger for FCM.

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_push.erl

Comment: did you find solution to this? or any good pointer?

Comment: https://github.com/abhay-s-rawat/xmpp-app-server

Comment: Thanks for that. I appreciate it